# l2fprod common components mirrors?

Tags: java, swing

I tried downloading from l2fprod main site but the java.net downloads folder is empty?

anyone know where else I can get it?

I am looking to for PropertyPane in swing for java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the latest version is not available for downloading, If you need that I think you have to get the source and build the jar. I found the binary for older version here,

http://olex.openlogic.com/package_versions/download/5693?package_version_id=1402&path=openlogic%2Fl2fprod-common%2F6.11-20061101%2Fl2fprod-common-6.11-20061101-all-bin.zip

Comment: You can use the maven build tool to compile the source, and i relive you can use the same to build the jar.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Helios, does it come with it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I never used it. I use Intellij Idea.